# Generate a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to generate a dictionary that is generating a=z, b=y, c=x, d=w and so on...
thanks.

```
import string
letter_count = dict( (key, 0) for key in string.ascii_lowercase )
letter_count
{'a': 'z', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'x'}
```

Comment: `dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, reversed(string.ascii_lowercase))) `

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the alphabet, `zip` it with the forward alphabet, and make the dict from that.

```
zip(string.ascii_lowercase, 
    reversed(string.ascii_lowercase))
```

Gives you the list of tuples you need:

```
[('a', 'z'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('d', 'w'), ('e', 'v'), ('f', 'u'), ('g', 't'), ('h', 's'), ('i', 'r'), ('j', 'q'), ('k', 'p'), ('l', 'o'), ('m', 'n'), ('n', 'm'), ('o', 'l'), ('p', 'k'), ('q', 'j'), ('r', 'i'), ('s', 'h'), ('t', 'g'), ('u', 'f'), ('v', 'e'), ('w', 'd'), ('x', 'c'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'a')]
```

Make your dict from that.

```
dict(
    zip(string.ascii_lowercase, 
        reversed(string.ascii_lowercase))
    )
```

If you aren't supposed to use `zip`:

```
abc = string.ascii_lowercase    # Short name for readability
d = dict( [ (abc[i], abc[25-i]) for i in range (len(abc)) ] )
```

Comment: hey
can you just write the whole code include the abc letters please? it kinda hard for me to understand

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service.
[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.  Asking for someone to do your coding for you is improper.

Comment: I'm asking for the complete code to understand better because I'm new at this and i want to learn by example, not because i wanted you to do my homework. a simple NO would be great.

Comment: Hmmm ... it's also possible that I misunderstand your misunderstanding.  `abc` is a simple variable name, so I don't have to keep typing `string.ascii_lowercase`.